# Running an external .rb file from within a rails 3 controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, command-line, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a rails 3 controller and a very simple ruby (.rb) file in my server index directory. I would like to run the file from within my controller- what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You could try `load`: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001417

Here's one example

```
# in your controller
def create
  load('/path/to/your/file.rb')
end
```

However, I would say it's bad practice in general to call Ruby code from Rails by running an outside script. I think you'd be better breaking your Ruby file into two:

1. One that encapsulates the script's functionality in classes and/or modules.
2. One that invokes said classes/modules from the command line.

Then, in your Rails app, just `require` #1 and use the classes/modules.

For example, suppose your script is currently called simple.rb and looks like this:

```
# simple.rb
puts 'Hello, world!'
```

You would then create `hello_world.rb` and do this:

```
# hello_world.rb
class HelloWorld
  def say_it
    puts 'Hello, world!'
  end
end
```

You would replace the contents of `simple.rb` with this:

```
require 'hello_world.rb'
HelloWorld.new.say_it
```

Then, in your controller, you could bypass `simple.rb` and just use the `HelloWorld` class directly:

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the script to run in it's own process? If so, check these out.

1. Background jobs: http://codeforpeople.rubyforge.org/svn/bj/trunk/README
2. Or delayed_job: https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job
3. Also, you can use script runner like this:

   system " RAILS_ENV=#{RAILS_ENV}   ruby  #{RAILS_ROOT}/script/runner   'MyModel.my_method(some_param)'  & "

The & at the end will put the task into another process.